# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, dbnull

I think I am suppose to use something like this but I am not sure how to modify it to work for DateTime because upon doing so it tells me DateTime can not be null. So how can I change this or is there a better method to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

What I'm trying to set

```
startDateTime = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate;
```

What I think it should look similar to

```
RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate == What goes here(string.Empty) ? (object)DBNull.Value : RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate);
```

Comment: Which is a `DateTime?` (nullable) and which `DateTime` (non-nullable)? Nullable types have `Value` property that denotes the actual value (if not `null`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using a RadDateTimePicker control, in which case the `SelectedDate` property is **not** a `DateTime` value. [It's a `Nullable<DateTime>`](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/radcalendar.net2-telerik.webcontrols.raddatepicker-selecteddate.html). That means you should probably do this:

```
 startDateTime = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate ?? default(DateTime);
```

Just be careful: if no date was selected, you'll end up with a January 1st, 0001 as your date, and not DBNull like you expect.

Moreover, I see you casting to `Object` here, which tells me you're probably about to make a big mistake. It looks like the `startDateTime` is going to be assigned to the value of an SqlParameter object, and in order for this variable to be able to hold items of both the DateTime and DBNull types it must have a type of `Object`. If you later create your SqlParameter using the `AddWithValue()` method, the method will likely **not** guess the parameter type correctly, because all it will see is the `Object` type. When this happens you can get severe performance penalties, as the type mismatch can force per-row conversions in the database or prevent good use of indexes.

If you're really set on your current path, you could do this instead:

```
 startDateTime = (RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate.HasValue)?
           (Object)RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate.Value
          :(Object)DBNull.Value;
```

But again: I strongly advise against it.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear where `DBNull` comes into the picture, but if you're trying to set a non-nullable `DateTime` to the value of a nullable `DateTime` then you'll need to supply a default value in the case of a `null`.  You can use the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) for this:

```
someNonNullableDateTime = someNullableDateTime ?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

The idea is that `someNullableDateTime` *might* contain a `null` value at runtime, and `someNonNullableDateTime` *can't* be assigned a `null` value.  Since the compiler can't enforce this, it throws a compilation error.  So you give the runtime code an option to either use the value or, if there's no value, use a default.

Answer (score 3):

If you're okay with `default(DateTime)` if the nullable is null then:

```
DateTime startDateTime = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Alternatively if you want another value e.g. `DateTime.MaxValue` when the nullable is null then you can pass in your default value:

```
DateTime startDateTime = nullableDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

DateTime can't be null. It's default is DateTime.MinValue.

```
if (YourDate.HasValue)
{
   RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate =  YourDate;
}
```

or

```
adDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate= YourDate?? DateTime.MinValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `startDateTime` is a `DateTime` and `RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate` is a `DateTime?`:

```
startDateTime = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate.HasValue
    ? RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate.Value
    : DateTime.MinValue;
```

Alternatively, make `startDateTime` nullable.

Comment: Also: `startDateTime = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate ?? default(DateTime);` means exactly the same thing, in half the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? selected = RadDateTimePickerBegin.SelectedDate;

if(selected.HasValue)
{
  startDateTime = selected.Value;
}
```

You need to make sure there actually *is* a selected datetime.